# React Error: You cannot render a <Router> inside another <Router>. You should never have more than one in your app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[index.js]

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import clayful from 'clayful/client-js';

import axios from 'axios';

clayful.config({
  client: 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6ImE0Mzg5MjhjNWZkNjFiNzkwNzc5OTU3MGRiZmUyYzE5ZTQ...'
});

clayful.install('request', require('clayful/plugins/request-axios')(axios));

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

[App.js]

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Route, Router } from "react-router-dom"; 
import LandingPage from './pages/LandingPage/LandingPage';
import LoginPage from './pages/LoginPage/LoginPage';
import RegisterPage from './pages/RegisterPage/RegisterPage';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Route path="/" element={<LandingPage />} /> 
      <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />   
      <Route path="/register" element={<RegisterPage />} />
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

React Error: You cannot render a  inside another . You should never have more than in your app> error occurs. Give them a hand.
Is "react-router-dom" the problem?
Is it because of "react6" or do we need to downgrade to "react5"?

Comment: Isn't the error pretty explicit? I know next to nothing in React, yet I understand "You cannot render a router inside another. You should never have more than one router in your app."

Answer (score 2):

You're using two routers, as the error message suggests.

You have one in index.js:

```
<BrowserRouter>
```

And another in App.js

```
<Router>
```

Try it without the `<Router>` in App.js.

Answer (score 2):

Both `BrowserRouter` and `Router` are considered to be routers. It looks like you may have a typo and should replace `<Router>` with `<Routes>` in *App.js*.

Answer (score -1):

App.js in
Router -> Routes Change.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).